# What are the definitions for "hard problem" and "easy problem"?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-classes

Take for example the following sentence:

> Computing a hash for a message is "easy"; retrieving the message from the hash is "hard".

Intuitively, I can perfectly understand what's written there. But, **in mathematical terms**, when is a problem considered hard and when is it considered easy?

I know that easy/hard should not be confused with "efficient", and I know that efficiency has to do with polynomial time complexity. Does it mean that hardness has nothing to do with asymptotic time complexity?

Comment: Likely this depends on the context. Usually, one can say a problem is easy if it can be solved in polynomial time. Similarly, a problem is said to be hard if there is no known polynomial time algorithm for it, e.g. the problem is say NP-complete.

Comment: In most cases "hard" means that its resource-need grows exponentially with the input (i.e. no essentially faster solutions as trial by one exist). But it is a highly inexact answer.

Comment: There's *difficult*, and there's *difficult, Asian style*: anywhere between *wouldn't know how* to *beyond machines&mortals*. Is there *any* way to *retrieving the message from [a fixed size] hash? (I wouldn't call something with length not dwarfed by message length for long messages a *hash*.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not technical terms, so they don't have precise definitions. A problem is "hard" if it requires (or we think it requires) "large" computational resources to solve, and "easy" if it doesn't. "Large" depends on context but, in most contexts, a problem that can be solved in polynomial time is considered "easy".

Comment: I guess that's why, so far, I struggled to find something in the literature without luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught in my Computer Science Algorithms class at IIT back in 1992 that "easy" problems are solved with a time/resource complexity of at worst X^3.  This makes problems with solutions of x^4 or worse "hard" problems, as well as problems that have an exponential resource characteristic.  But a "Google" search today does not provide for "hard" polynomial problems.  Focus of "hardness" has been on NPC and NP-Hard for decades and the P vs. NP question.

Comment: (You use both `X` and  `x`, $n$ being more common.)

Answer (score 0):

My definition: Its easy if my computer can find a solution within a few days. And it’s hard if my computer cannot solve it within six months.

That’s instances, not problems. The travelling salesman problem is easy for 20 nodes. Problems are easy / hard if interesting instances are easy / hard. Matrix multiplication is easy, but multiplying two 250,000 by 250,000 matrices is hard.

At some point you decide what’s easy / hard for you.